# How to use routing of angular2 and .net mvc Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core-1.0

I am doing authentication and authorization of pages on the server side. on index pages of each controller. But inside each index page I want to use angular 2 hence I want to use angular 2 routing.

I have tried like

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:''
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { TestSuiteComponent } from './testsuite/testsuite.component'
//import {InputTextModule, CalendarModule, DataTable} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataTableModule, SharedModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, DataTableModule, SharedModule, RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: 'TestSuiteEditor/Index',
            component: TestSuiteComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'Home/Index',
            component: TestSuiteComponent
        }
    ])],
    declarations: [AppComponent,TestSuiteComponent],   
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

on testsuite.component.ts page

```
import { Directive, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataTableModule, SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { TestSuite } from './testsuite';


    @Component({
        // moduleId: module.id,
        selector: 'testsuite-header',
        template: `
    <div class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px 10px;border-bottom: 0 none">
        <i class="fa fa-search" style="float:left;margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
        <input #gb type="text" pInputText size="50" style="float:left" placeholder="Global Filter">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-datatable ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper">
    <p-dataTable [value]="testSuites" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true" [globalFilter]="gb" [editable]="true">
        <p-column field="testSuiteId" header="TestSuites (startsWith)"  [style]="{'width':'10%'}" [filter]="true" [editable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="projectId" header="ProjectId (contains)"  [style]="{'width':'10%'}" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [editable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="name" header="Name (startsWith)"  [style]="{'width':'30%'}" [filter]="true" [editable]="true"></p-column>
        <p-column field="description" header="Description (endsWith)"  [style]="{'width':'40%'}" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="endsWith" [editable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="isActive" header="IsActive (endsWith)"  [style]="{'width':'10%'}" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="endsWith" [editable]="true"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
    </div>
    </div>                `,
       // providers: [TestSuiteService]




        })
export class TestSuiteComponent{}
```

Home/Index.cshtml

```
<testsuite-header>Loading....</testsuite-header>
```

but it throwing an error of

Cannot find primary outlet to load 'TestSuiteComponent'

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add router-outlet in your application. You can define router-outlet in AppComponent like this-

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So your AppComponent will looks like this-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:`
<!-- Routed views go here -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: I had added router outlet but we want to load the index page from server and then in that page edit delete operation through angular 2

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, thanks for your help

I have created the path similar to my MVC routing and added in routing.ts.

Since angular 2routing have feature of loading the active url so it automatically loads the component which is assign to that URL.

Comment: can you please share more details